# Swift: find the index of a value in an array of classes and filter the array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a `class` defined as follows:

```
class placeData: Equatable {
var description : String
var selected : Bool

init (description : String, selected : Bool) {
    self.description = description
    self.selected = selected
    }
}
```

I then define an `array` as follows:

```
var placeDataArray = Array<placeData>()
```

And populate it with some items:

```
placeDataArray = [placeData(description: "Afghanistan", selected: false), placeData(description: "Albania", selected: false)]
```

What I am looking to do is get the index of a description such as "Afghanistan" and then change `selected` to `true` from `false`. `indexOf` and `find` methods don't seem to work, unless I am using them incorrectly.

I am also trying to `filter` the `placeDataArray` for `true`  so that all of the `descriptions` with `true` values will appear in the variable I set. However, I am going about this the wrong way as well. I am fairly new to swift and can't seem to figure these out. Also, the array changes with user input hence the indexing and filtering.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your classes starting with a capital letter

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is this:

```
if let index = placeDataArray.indexOf ({ $0.description == "Afghanistan" })
{
    placeDataArray[index].selected = true
}
```

It does not require Equatable.

Similarly, you can use filter to show only selected items:

```
let selected = placeDataArray.filter { $0.selected == true }
```